# Is /etc/hosts still used to override DNS name resolution on Fedora?

Tags: linux, dns, fedora, systemd

I'm working on Fedora 31. I need to override DNS resolution for one domain. Using `/etc/hosts` I would add:

```
172.16.2.1    example.com
172.16.2.1    www.example.com
```

I'm not sure what I am supposed to do nowadays with Systemd. I can't find a discussion in the Fedora [System Administration Guide](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f31/system-administrators-guide/). The internet is returning noise and fodder.

How do we override DNS resolution for one name on Fedora 31 with Systemd?

---

Here is `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep -v '#' | sed -r '/^\s*$/d'
passwd:      sss files systemd
shadow:     files sss
group:       sss files systemd
hosts:      files dns myhostname
bootparams: files
ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss
netgroup:   sss
publickey:  files
automount:  files sss
aliases:    files
```

Comment: Look in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to see the order of sources for `hosts`, and if you have `files` there, before or after `dns`

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I added a cat of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. I don't think it makes a difference, though.

Comment: Your `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, for the `hosts` entry clearly show files (that means consulting `/etc/hosts`) before doing DNS queries. That means any application asking the OS to do name resolution will have its results coming from those sources, in order. Of course some application are free to do things on their own. For example browsers now uses DOH that is DNS over HTTPS and that will probably completely ignore your `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, modifying `/etc/hosts` is the proper way to override standard DNS.

It will not work if you are using [DNS over HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS) (DOH).

Some operating systems and browsers will require their internal DNS cahces to be flushed for immediate changes in name resolution.

Comment: Thanks @Keltari. Do you have a reference for Fedora 30 or 31? (I don't trust Systemd. Adding an entry to `/etc/hosts` may be the net result, but Systemd may have a new way to add the entry... Like Systemd did with changing a hostname.).

Comment: @jww No, but I have done it and it works.